# Difference between running a executable using Rtlinux command and scheduling a process/thread using FIFO policy

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, embedded-linux

I am newbie to Rtlinux and trying to understand the fundamentals. I read somewhere that an executable can also be ran using the **rtlinux** command but I didn't find much information about the command. What is the difference between running a executable using Rtlinux command and scheduling a process/thread using FIFO policy with rtlinux patch.

Thanks in advance!!

Update: Seen same command used in rtlinux book downloaded from [here](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/pdf/RTLinux-HOWTO.pdf): Page number : 7

```
The resulting object binary must be inserted into the kernel, where it will be executed by RTLinux.
Use the command 'rtlinux' (you need to be the 'root' to do so).
$ rtlinux start hello
```

Answer (score 1):

Since RTLinux is using a microkernel architechure it allows you to bypass any latencies introduced by the regular Linux kernel. Consider this sketch:

```
 ----- ----- -----
| App | App | App |                      (1)
 ----------------- --------- ---------
| Linux (RTL App) | RTL App | RTL App |  (2)
 -------------------------------------
|               RTLinux               |
 -------------------------------------
|                  HW                 |
 -------------------------------------
```

When scheduling your program with Linux's FIFO scheduler it will run at layer (1). The Linux kernel is itself is the lowest (usually) prioritized "process" in the RTLinux scheduler.

But when you compile your program as an RTLinux module and run it at layer (2), it is able to preempt the Linux kernel with minimum latency when an interrupt is received for instance.

NOTE: As far as I know RTLinux is not being actively developed anymore. Consider looking into [Xenomai](http://xenomai.org/) or the [PREEMPT_RT](https://rt.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Main_Page) patchset.